# DELETE FROM table USING a, b

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

I have a `DELETE` query defined in [this dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-FZF6XBV) which ends with:

```
    ......
    DELETE
    FROM
         data_table AS d
    USING
         ref1 AS r1,
         ref2 AS r2
    WHERE
         (d.ref_time = r2.ref_time)
      OR (d.ref_time = r1.ref_time) AND d.timestamp <= (SELECT max_timestamp FROM maxts)
```

In the above, `ref1` and `ref2` are two CTEs which I'm using to get relevant info from the `status_table` for use in deciding which records from `data_table` I can delete.

The above query deletes 24 records from `data_table`, 6 of which are from the `ref2 r2` part ([see here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z78PQRI3)) and 18 of which are from the `ref1 r1` part ([see here](https://dbfiddle.uk/g-C1Zqkm)).

But when the `ref2` CTE results in no records, like in [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-nWmFCuY) in which I've just commented out the two relevant `INSERT` lines (marked with a `NOT INSERTING` comment), actually now the `DELETE` query doesn't delete any records at all.  I still want it to delete the 18 records associated with the `ref1` CTE (i.e. based on the part after the `OR` keyword in the `WHERE` statement).

I'm sure I'm misusing and misunderstanding the `DELETE ... USING a, b` construct, but what is the correct way to write this query?  I know I can put half of the `OR` into a 'dummy' CTE of its own, the the other half as the actual query, but how do I do this without resorting to that approach?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from `ref1 AS r1,ref2 AS r2` which is almost equivalent to `ref1 AS r1 CROSS JOIN ref2 AS r2`, ie you execute a **Cartesian product** of N rows coming from `ref1` and M rows coming from `ref2`, resulting in (N*M) rows. When N=0 or M=0, then N*M=0 so that you get no resulting rows.

I'm not sure that you really want to operate a Cartesian product here, rather than a kind of union between the rows coming from `ref1` and `ref2` while differentiating these rows in the `WHERE` clause so that to apply different conditions applying to the rows from `ref1` and the rows from `ref2`. To do so, you can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN ... ON False` clause instead of `CROSS JOIN` and then test if `ref1.ref_time IS NULL` or `ref2.ref_time IS NULL` :

```
......
DELETE
FROM
     data_table AS d
USING
     ref1 AS r1 FULL OUTER JOIN ref2 AS r2 ON False
WHERE
     CASE 
       WHEN r2.ref_time IS NULL
       THEN d.ref_time = r1.ref_time AND d.timestamp <= (SELECT max_timestamp FROM maxts)
       ELSE d.ref_time = r2.ref_time
    END
```

All these explanations may be more understandable when looking at this basic [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pHbwHlLC)

Comment: OK thanks, it helps a lot knowing that `t, u` is equivalent to `t CROSS JOIN u`... I hadn't appreciated that this was effectively what my `USING` was referring to... I had thought that the `r1` and `r2` in `USING ref1 AS r1, ref2 AS r2` were somehow independent... but it's actually doing a `CROSS JOIN`... explains a lot!